# Multiple filters for ng-repeat with track by

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a ng-repeat with filters put as shown below before. For some reason it didnt work in the web server and i think its because of duplicate items not allowed in browser DOM so i had to put "track by item.id". Please see the code below.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search:date | filter:filterFrontPage track by item.id">
```

The only issue with above code is that items are not loaded by having "filterFrontPage" filter as well which filters a boolean value from an item. The whole thing works fine when i have it changed to the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search:date track by item.id">
```

Thus, using the above, how would i add one more filter to filter a boolean value in a variable. I cant seems to get this working by using "filter:search:date:{isActive:true}". Please let me know as to what can be done to get this working.

**Update 1:**

I have removed "date" as i used it long ago. "search" is for the following and that works fine.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search posts" ng-model="search.$" />
```

Ideally filterFrontPage is written to filter items by isActive variable true/false;

Comment: DO you have a plunkr by any chance?

Comment: Its a big project i have right now and i wasnt using plunkr. Would you be able to identify as to why that kind of a filter wont work?

Comment: Neither of those filters does seem right. I doubt that `date` is a comparator or `filterFrontPage` one of `string`, `Object` or `function`.

Comment: Check my update 1 in the post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use parentheses around the filtered collection, i.e.:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in (items | filter:search:date) track by item.id">
```

Comment: Thank you very much.But why is it that when i add it like this "item in (items | filter:search:{isFrontPage:true}) track by $index", this method here does not get called.

app.filter('filterFrontPage', function () {
  return function (items) {
console.log('hello');

}
});

Comment: If you could provide a fiddle/plunk for this, you could get more help.

Comment: Okay using your code, how would i filter a boolean value in an item?